# Show that the interval $[0, 1]$ cannot be partitioned into two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $B = A + a$ for some real number $a$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

I stumbled upon this problem on Putnam and Beyond by Gelca et. al. It’s problem 9 in chapter 1.1.

I have tried to do proof by contradiction by supposing that in fact $[0, 1]$ can be partitioned into two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $B = A + a$ for some real number $a$.

Assume $a$ is positive W.L.O.G. The first thing I did was to try to split $[0, 1]$ into two disjoint sets. There exists $k > 0$ such that $[0, 1] = [0, k] \cup (k, 1]$. Let $A = [0, k]$. I tried to reach a contradiction by showing that there is no real positive number $a$ such that $[0 + a, k + a] = (k, 1]$. So, $a > k$ and $k + a = 1$. Combining these two conditions, $a > \frac{1}{2}$ and $k < \frac{1}{2}$. But there seems to be no problem with $a$.

And I can’t think of any other way of contradicting the statement. A hint instead of a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't rely on the title of your MSE questions for important information. The body should be self-contained. You haven't actually given the statement of the problem in the body. As for a hint: consider the lub and glb of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: What you have done proves nothing. You cannot use any speciifc form of $A$ and $B$. They need not be intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivial to show the statement for $|a|\ge1$. W.L.O.G we can say that $0<a<1$.
 Now, let's suppose that sets $A$ and $B$ s.t. they satisfy the given conditions exist.

***1. case***
$a< \frac{1}{2}$
Considering that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, the fact that $a>0$ and that element $1$ has to be in one of them it must be $1\in B$, this means that $\max A=1-a$. Similarly $\min B=a$. This implies, not only $[0,a)\subset A$, but also $2a\in A$. Continuing like this we can see that all subsets of $[0,1]$ of the form $[2ka,(2k+1)a)$ are subsets of $A$ and all subsets of the form $[(2k+1)a,(2k+2)a)$ are subsets of $B$. Keep in mind that $k\in \mathbb{N}$, until $2ka=1$. This means that there exists some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. $2na=1$, which would mean $1\in A$, but of course that is impossible, therefore a contradiction.

***2. case***
$a>\frac{1}{2}$
You can simply show that both $A$ and $B$ in this case would have to be intervals, since $\min B=a>\frac{1}{2}$ and $2a\notin A$, because if it were that $A$ wouldn't be a subset of $[0,1]$. Because $max A=1-a$, that leaves $(1-a,a)\not\subset A\cup B$. So obviously $A\cup B \neq [0,1]$. Contradiction!

***3. case***
$a=\frac{1}{2}$
In this case, $\max A=\min B=\frac{1}{2}$. Implying $A \cap B=\{\frac{1}{2}\}$. And again, a contradiction.

From all of this we can conclude that such sets $A$ and $B$ that satisfy the given conditions don't exist.

Comment: @AsafKaragila why was my previous answer deleted?

Comment: *You* have flagged and requested it to be removed. We can't "unaccept" an answer, only delete it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understand. For future reference if such scenario were to happen again, should I post a new answer or edit the already accepted answer?

Comment: I don't see why you need case 2 and 3 at all. In case 1 you never use $a < \frac 12$ when you figure $[0,a)\subset A$.  From there $[0,a)+a = [a,2a)\subset B$ and so $2a \le 1; 2a\ne B; 2a\ne 1$ .